# Revit Document.itTemplate property

Tags: revit-api

Trying to figure out a way to determine if a newly created, unsaved Revit file is a project or a template.  the Document has a property for "isFamily" returning true or false, but none for isTemplate.  Since there is no file path, I cant examine the file name and extension.  Is there a way to determine if an opened, unsaved document is a project vs a template?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible.
I can only imagine that you could check if the Path is empty and then use the Document Title to proof if it contains the default Template name prefix (something like "template*"), but of course you cannot be 100% sure that it is actually a template besides the prefix is dependent on the current Revit culture.

Comment: I discovered the application event DocumentCreatingEventArgs contains a property for DocumentType which promises to return "Document" or "Template"... https://www.revitapidocs.com/2015/cf00a154-4096-e10c-fb3c-a8eda1f58200.htm.  I solved my problem another way so didn't really drill in to it.